LocalDateTime - issue in time display in database
I need to save a date with time in an Oracle database.
I have used LocalDateTime in my entity, and the date with time is showing correctly in the Eclipse console, but there is a mismatch in time when I check the database column.
Can anyone help with this?
Output needed with correct time

As you can see you have 5 and half hour difference between your Host and Database. I am guessing (may be bad guess) when writing on database, database is doing adjustment. My suggestion consider to set proper timezone for your db and make sure your server(where spring-boot is running) also have same timezone

The LocalDateTime javadoc specifies that it represents a DateTime without any timezone in ISO-8601. I wont be suprised if the db is representing it in UTC which would explain the 5 and half hour gap. However, this is likely the incorrect class to use, I m thinking Instant or ZonedDateTime might be a better fit.

Does this answer your question? Saving date in UTC in Oracle Timestamp column

Continuing above comment, try
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = UTC
this if you are using application.properties.

check this link: Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

You haven't stated what your column type is...

Depending on what your database and your JDBC driver can do you’re probably better off with using OffsetDateTime in UTC in Java and timestamp with time zone in your database.

For some reason, you have now removed all illustrative postings from the question and have replaced them with nothing. That's probably going to get the question closed

State the exact data type of your column.

Provide an [MCVE]

“is a mismatch in time when I check the database column.” — give a concrete example.

You’ve not provided enough detail, and have ignored the requests for details posted in the Comments.
So all I can say is:

For columns of a data type akin to the SQL standard type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, you must use the Java class OffsetDateTime.

In Oracle Database: TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE and TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE types.


For columns of a data type akin to the SQL standard type TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, you must use the Java class LocalDateTime.

In Oracle Database: TIMESTAMP type.



See Oracle Database documentation.
